# What's going on with my Aloe plant?

Tags: houseplants, watering, succulents, aloe

I got it from Costco about half a year ago and it hasn't had many problems in the time that I've had it- in fact, it has flowered about 5 or 6 times since I bought it. I had to leave it at my old house for about 3 weeks after heading off to my university's dorms and during that time my family did not water it or anything- it just remained outside during the hot and humid wave through Missouri. Now, the leaves towards the bottom have turned yellow and brown and the newer growth is somehow shriveling but squishy at the same time and the tips are turning brown. And yet, somehow, it is growing a new stalk of flowers. Is it overwatered? Underwatered? Something else? Am I overreacting?[image]
note: Some of the leaves have been broken due to traveling. I did my best to cushion them but some didn't make it and have been broken for a while.

Comment: Flowering "5 or 6 times" in 6 months seems pretty unusual to me. I suspect it was  already on its way to dying when you bought it, and all that flowering activity (and the latest flower stalk) is just its final attempt to  reproduce. Neither plants nor humans live for ever! A succulent like an aloe shouldn't "die through lack of watering" for just 3 weeks. I don't water most of my cacti and succulents at all for 3 to 6 months after they flower, to give them a good rest before they start growing again.

Comment: Welcome Aimee Laws! Thanks for the great description, but we really need some pictures of the plant, and a bit more information. What watering schedule are you using? Was that new flower stalk there before you left, or did it just grow after the plant got some water? You're not over-reacting. The plant obviously has problems, but I wouldn't necessarily write it off yet, especially since it has new growth. The sooner we can look at it, the better!

Comment: @Sue I completely forgot to upload the picture I took, sorry! Do you need any more?

Comment: No problem forgetting the picture! It's nice and clear! Unfortunately, I'm not the aloe expert here, but we have plenty. One of them might ask for a different view, but this might be just enough!